# Unable to mailmerge into a template word document when launched on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, mailmerge

I am working on a django application in which users input is inserted into a template word document. I used the mailmerge library to achieve this. It was all working fine on my local server but when I deployed the app to heroku it started giving me errors. The system doesn’t crush or anything. The ajax request made to call the function that mailmerges the document is returning the error function  The error I get on the heroku logs is:

```
    File "/app/input/merge.py", line 69, in merge
2019-12-02T07:55:48.252446+00:00 app[web.1]: document.write('documents/'+name+'.docx')
2019-12-02T07:55:48.252449+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mailmerge.py", line 120, in write
2019-12-02T07:55:48.252451+00:00 app[web.1]: with ZipFile(file, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as output:
```

I don't understand why it is giving me this error. The documents generated are saved into a folder named documents in the root directory of the project.

Comment: You didn't show the actual error. But this will never work, you can't store things on the filesystem in Heroku because it is ephemeral.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman does this mean there is no way I could store the generated files?

Comment: It means you have to store them somewhere permanent, like S3.